# AngularJS template bindings don't update on data change, but do update when I read the model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a custom directive with an isolate scope that uses two-way data binding back to the parent scope. The scope/bindings all appear to be working correctly, but the template/view is not automatically updating the bound properties in the dom when they change. I can force the dom to update by reading the directive's model.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vPGm1oO0sSaHVvcrp2Ev

Note: In this plunkr example I use am using the isActive property on the wiglet 1's scope as the bound property. Note that I print the value to the console when the scope is created and also when it is updated 2 seconds later via a window.timeout... so you can see at this point that while the data has changed, the dom has not. To see the dom change click the 'print' button on either of the wiglets, which simply prints the value of isActive to console again. This causes the dom to update.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS only updates bound variables during a scope digest cycle; this normally happens automatically for Angular managed events (`ng-click`, etc.), but in asynchronous code, such as a `setTimeout`, you must manually call `Scope#$apply()` or `Scope#$digest()`:

```
$window.setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.wiglets[0].isActive = true;
    console.log("Wiglet 1 isActive:", $scope.wiglets[0].isActive);
  });
}, 2000);
```

This is so common with `setTimeout` that AngularJS has a built in service, called `$timeout`, that does this for you:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.wiglets[0].isActive = true;
  console.log("Wiglet 1 isActive:", $scope.wiglets[0].isActive);
}, 2000);
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XDK06uhYMNcI6fs6SuHP?p=preview